# keyboard wont work!

Tags: keyboard, uefi

I have recently installed elementaryOS on to my sisters HP streampad as the dreaded windows killed the system with updates.
Everything seems to work fine however the keyboard does not work and im at a loss with it. 
It works fine in the bios which is UEFI but not once the OS is loaded?
I have looked around online but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [this site](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Windows/Linux-on-the-HP-Stream-tablet/td-p/6675613)

It says:

> The Secure Boot option needs to be disabled within the UEFI setup menu.
>   A OTG adapter and powered USB hub with an external mouse and keyboard are required to do the installation.  An un-powered hub may work but it will read the USB drive slowly and may fail reading it since the Stream's USB port provides very little power from the internal battery.

This might do the trick for you and maybe trying after the installation ends to see if it detects the KB.